# R Remove padding from datatable cells

Tags: css, r, shiny, padding, dt

I have a datatable in my shiny web app in which I have inserted checkboxes. However, my actual dataset is quite large. Therefore I would like to compress the datatable respectively reduce the padding.
Although I have already found some approaches, this did not work with the checkboxes.

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advane!

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
  ),
  
  server<-function(input, output, session) {
    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput<-function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    # a sample data frame
    values <- reactiveValues(res=data.frame(
      iris %>% slice(10),
      v2=shinyInput(checkboxInput, 10, 'v2_', value=FALSE)
    )
    )
    
    # render the table containing shiny inputs
    output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(values$res, escape = F),
      server=FALSE,
      escape=FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a little [CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). Strictly speaking of the padding, that's straight forward. This rule targets table data cells elements (`<td>`) contained within the table with the id "x1"

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
    tags$style(HTML("
      #x1 td {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }                
    "))
  )
```

This compacts it some. If you want to compact it more, you'll need to find what's driving the row height then target that. For example, the checkboxes have a bottom margin. You could remove that as well. If you're not aware, you can see the applied css by using using your browser's devtools. For Chrome, right click on a row and select "Inspect"